# How to check if a UIbutton is the correct answer by pressing it

Tags: swift, uibutton

I created 4 UIbuttons in a single 4-option question. The code here is to check if the correct answer is getting chosen. Why the if statement returns false every time? I know something wrong here, but I am new to swift and cannot fix it by myself. Please help, thanks a lot!

```
let question1 = Question(question: "This was the only US President to serve more than two consecutive terms.", options: ["George Washington", "Woodrow Wilson", "Andrew Jackson", "Franklin D. Roosevelt"], correctAnswer: "Franklin D. Roosevelt")

@IBAction func checkAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let correctAnswer = question1.correctAnswer

    if sender.currentTitle == correctAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in the `selectedQuestionDict` dictionary? And what are the titles of your buttons?

Comment: With the limited code you supplied, one can only tell button's title is not equal to `selectedQuestionDict["Answer"]`. Print them both and compare them.

Comment: Check if your dictionary returns a proper value. And how does it return a different answer for a different question? Will your `selectedQuestionDict` change?

Comment: I have  add some code there, please take a look.

Comment: Am I allowed to compare `String` to `String?`?

Comment: @joijioj yes it is allowed

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more efficient to assign tags to the buttons and use the index (3 in this case) for the correct answer rather than a string?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
@IBAction func checkAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let correctAnswer = selectedQuestionDict["Answer"]

    if sender.titleLabel?.text == correctAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the title of the button for the `selected` (or more generally the `normal` state):

```
let btn = UIButton()
btn.setTitle("Franklin D. Roosevelt", for: .normal)
//Or
btn.setTitle("Franklin D. Roosevelt", for: .selected)
```

For more details on `currentTitle`, have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624032-currenttitle).